# Monitor document using MutationObserver within function

Tags: javascript, dom, scope, mutation-observers

#### Background

I want to step through a paginated Ajax table and pull out some image `src` attributes that exist prior to fallback images being swapped in, and store them in an array. While I can easily monitor changes to the attributes with a global MutationObserver, I'd like to only start storing these in the target array when the user clicks a specific button. On click, I would page through the table, store the mutated `src` attributes in the array, and then stop storing once the process is complete, so the user is then free to manually page through the table without modifying the array further.

### Question

Is it possible to initialise a MutationObserver inside a function? If so, what am I doing wrong with the toy example below, which doesn't return the array of mutation objects that I expected? It seems that `cb` is never called.

```js
function test() {
    var a = [];
    colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'red'];

    var cb = function(mutations, observer) {
        for (var mutation of mutations) {
            console.log('In mutations loop:', a);
            console.log(mutation);
            // Here I would pull out the img src attribute
            a.push(mutation);
        }
    };

    var observer = new MutationObserver(cb);

    observer.observe(document, {
        attributes: true, 
        attributeOldValue: true,
        childList: true, 
        subtree: true
    });

    for (var i=0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        // For my motivating problem this loop would click through
        // the table, triggering img src mutations.  
        console.log(colors[i]);
        document.body.style.cssText = 'background:' + colors[i] + ';'; 
    }

    observer.disconnect();

    console.log('a:', a);
    return(a);
}

test()
```

Comment: MutationObserver's callback is invoked asynchronously as a *microtask*. It happens **after** your function completes. Since you disconnect the observer, it's never called, indeed. Switch to async code e.g. via Promises and/or async/await keywords.

Comment: Wow, so simple - thank you @wOxxOm. So how would I disconnect the observer after calling the function? I guess this would require returning the observer from the function, but I'll be returning the array. Would I just wrap the call to `test` (a modified version without the observer set up) in a second function, which creates the observer, calls `test`, and disconnects the observer?